# Is there a list of all of the Python Libraries?

Tags: python, scripting, libraries

If there is could you provide a link to a website? Please do not down vote this question because I just signed up for stackoverflow, and I wanna still be able to ask questions.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Built in you can find on the python site.  Most widely used ones you can find on PyPI.  But there's no exhaustive list of libraries that are available somewhere on the web.

Comment: *all*, no. It's impossible. Most of them: yes, [`PyPi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) You can use `pip` or `easy_install` to install packages from there.

Comment: Also, you don't need reputation to ask questions.  Anybody can ask a question.

Comment: You may have confused us with google.  You can ask google anything, try it out.

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there too many Python libraries?

Comment: Yes, by two.  A couple of them have to go.  Kinda like a large family that has too many children and find it beneficial to weed some out.

Comment: It helps to ask smarter questions.  This isn't one of them.

Comment: It's impossible because there are so many closed-source, internal libraries companies write and never share, or awful libraries no one wants to dig out of some forgotten corner of the web, and I can just write up a library right now, not tell anyone, and defeat any plan to index all the libraries.

Comment: Oh, ok. How is this not a smart question?

Comment: @JonRylie13 - Because it's kinda like asking for a list of all books in existence.  Who could possibly give an accurate answer?

Comment: That sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* the libraries? No. However, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) has a guide to all the built-in libraries, and the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) has a lot of 3rd-party libraries.